# Dart 2.18: StreamTransformer for InputElement Field

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to apply `StreamTransformer` for `InputElement` field using `Dart 2.18.2`. I'm experiencing the following errors:

**Transformer error:**

```
Line 18: The argument type 'StreamTransformer<Object?, Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<String?, dynamic>'.
```

**Null Safety error:**

```
Line 8: The method 'contains' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

**My HTML**

```
<h4>Email address:</h4>
<input />
<div style="color: red"></div>
```

**My Dart Code:**

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
void main() {
  final InputElement input = querySelector('input') as InputElement;
  final DivElement div = querySelector('div') as DivElement;
  final transformer = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (value, sink) {
      if(value.contains('@')) {
        sink.add('valid email');
      } else {
        sink.addError('Invalid');
      }
    }
  );
  
  input.onInput
    .map( (event) => (event.target as InputElement).value)
    .transform(transformer)
    .listen(
    (value) => print('Email corrected!'),
    onError: (err) => print(err),
  );
}
```

**My Code with Line Numbers:**
[image]

Can someone please point out what I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add `String` in `handleData` to tell `Transformer` that `String` data will be transmitted, therefore, adding this resolved the error.

```
final transformer = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (String? value, sink) {
      if(value!.contains('@')) {
        sink.add('valid email');
      } else {
        sink.addError('Invalid');
      }
    }
  );
```

**Note:** I would be happy to see any better solution that automatically detects types, etc.